# Aladdin's magic ring and lamp

Tags: identify-this-movie

I recall seeing an Aladdin movie (not the [obvious Disney one](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103639/)) a few years back (more than 3 but I'm unsure of when). I either saw it on TV or Netflix but it isn't on the previously rented list on Netflix and I couldn't find it on imdb despite vigorous searching. The movie wasn't black and white or a musical, it was in English, it was live action, and I remember thinking the special effects were "good" but don't recall any scenes with special effects so I can't give detail. I remember very little so here's everything I can remember.

Aladdin and Jafar head to the cave of wonders. Aladdin explores the cave, finds the lamp and returns it to the entrance. Jafar takes the lamp and kicks Aladdin back down as the cave's stairs collapse leaving Aladdin trapped inside. Aladdin rubs a magic ring that I think he already had (I want to say his brother gave it to him) which causes a genie to appear. The genie will grant 3 wishes and Aladdin uses the first to escape. He then returns to Agrabah to find that Jafar had used a wish to take over. Aladdin says that his second wish is to obtain the magic lamp to which the genie of the ring responds "oh no, that's simply not possible. The genie of the lamp is much more powerful than I am". So Aladdin instead wishes he was a prince and the plot goes on.

At the climax (I'm less sure about this part) Aladdin squares off against Jafar while both genies fight (which has a nice symmetry to it). The genie of the ring was simply trying not to die (since he knew he couldn't win). After Aladdin beats Jafar the genie of the lamp stops fighting and the genie of the ring is still alive.

The genie of the ring had a very friendly personality: he wanted to be Aladdin's friend. The genie of the lamp, on the other hand, was very cold: he was only here to grant wishes (in fact I don't think he ever even talked). The genie of the ring was played by an actor (I want to say blue clothes) without special effects as opposed to the genie of the lamp who never had legs and was completely a special effect.

I don't remember any actors or anything useful but since I couldn't find any movie description that mentioned a magic ring I'm going to guess that this is a fairly uniquely identifiable movie. After some google searching, I found [this page](https://dettoldisney.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/aladdin-vs-aladdin-and-the-enchanted-lamp/) which talks about the original Aladdin story. It says the original story did contain a genie in a magic ring which freed Aladdin from the cave. I didn't read much of the page but when I saw the part talking about exchanging old lamps for new I remembered a scene in this movie where Jasmine falls for this trick. Although I don't remember if it was Aladdin or Jafar in disguise.

My inability to find this movie made me think that this was somehow a dream. But I've never read the Aladdin story and had only looked up details when trying to find this movie. So the few details I somehow knew of the original story makes me think that somebody must have made this movie based on the original story. Perhaps this was a lesser known movie made for TV (like SciFi movies). It's definitely not [Aladdin and the Death Lamp (2012)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2415710/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) nor is it [Aladin (2009)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1227762/).

Comment: Could it be _Arabian Nights_ from 2000?  It was an American made mini-series starring John Leguizamo.

Comment: @steelerfan Feel free to post something like that as an answer, possibly also linking a short clip or advertisement for comparison. It's not bad if it isn't the correct movie, because someone else looking for something similar might be looking for that one in particular.

Comment: @Mario Well, I usually don't like doing that unless I am confident that I am correct.  I always just give a suggestion to what I _think_ that it might be.  If the OP says that is correct, then I will gladly post it as an answer.

Comment: @steelerfan I found it on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FI2B7BYVa9E) around the 2 hour mark. The genies look and act just like I remember (memory errors aside). The genie of the ring exists, the lamp is stronger, and they fight. This must be it. I must've seen a couple episodes and assumed it was a movie. How many episodes were about Aladdin and how close were the other things I thought? Looking forward to hearing a bit more about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are searching for [*Arabian Nights*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabian_Nights_(miniseries)), a miniseries that aired in 2000.  This consisted of five separate stories.  The story that you are looking for is ***Aladdin and the magic lamp***

The part that you are referring to with "Jafar" is probably the character, "Mustappa" in this story:

> **Aladdin meets a mysterious traveler named Mustappa (Hugh Quarshie),**
>   who claims to have been a friend of Aladdin's father and is willing to
>   pay him much money to do a 'simple' task. Aladdin agrees and meets
>   Mustappa at the entrance of the Cave of Wonders. Mustappa gives
>   Aladdin a ring, and swears "by Hector's feathers", that Aladdin will
>   not see his wedding day if he betrays Mustappa.
>
> Aladdin enters the Cave and walks through a Terracotta Army until he
>   finds the lamp. He races back to the entrance, where Mustappa asks
>   Aladdin to give him the lamp before he helps him out. Aladdin refuses,
>   believing Mustappa will take the lamp and leave him in the cave.
>   Mustappa, enraged, closes the cave's entrance and abandons Aladdin. In
>   desperation, **Aladdin rubs Mustappa's ring and summons the Genie of the
>   Ring (John Leguizamo) who reluctantly frees Aladdin from the cave.**

John Leguizamo plays both the Genie of the lamp and the Genie of the ring who do have contradicting personalities.

The climax to the story is pretty accurate to what you're describing.

> Using the Genie of the Ring, Aladdin challenges Mustappa to a fight to
>   the death with their magic. Each Genie transforms into one beast after
>   another, until the Ring Genie is trapped in a giant mousetrap.
>   Although Mustappa appears to have won, Aladdin is still a thief and is
>   able to pick-pocket Mustappa, taking the Lamp and thus stealing his
>   victory.